How to exclude a range in CSS media queries
Is there a way to exclude a certain range within a media query? F.e i have a min-max range of 1000-1500px. Now i wanna exclude the range 1100-1200px. Is this possible with one media query like: @media screen and (min-width:1000px) and (max-width: 1500px) and not((min-width: 1100px) and (max-width:1200px)){}
I tried this Line of Code but it doesnt work

Basically you can't exclude a range but you can tell it what properties to use in that range.

Unfortunately, CSS doesn't support the direct exclusion of a range within a media query like the syntax you've proposed. However, there are some workarounds you can use to achieve a similar effect.
One approach is to break down the range you want to exclude into two separate media queries and then combine them with the not keyword. Here's how you can do it:


@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1500px) {
  /* Styles for the range 1000px to 1500px */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  /* Styles for the range 1100px to 1200px (the range you want to exclude) */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1500px) and not all and (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  /* Styles for the range 1000px to 1500px excluding the range 1100px to 1200px */
}



This way, you define your main range, then the range you want to exclude, and finally, you combine them with the not keyword to exclude the latter from the former.
